# Which Client ID & Secret for Azure API Management Authorization Code Flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-api-management

**Background**

I have an instance of Azure API Managment that is configured to use Azure AD as the OAuth 2.0 identity provider.  In Azure AD, there are two *App Registrations*:

- (A) Azure APIM App Registration
- (B) Customer Application App Registration

  - Registered as Authorized client application of (A)
  - Customer application will authenticate against Azure AD before passing bearer token to Azure APIM.

In Postman, authenticating with Azure AD using *Client Credentials* grant type works fine using the Customer Application (B) client ID & secret to authenticate and call APIM endpoints.  This simulates the customer's service authenticating with Azure AD.

**Question**

Which client ID and client Secret should the *customer's developers* use in Postman if they want to test APIM using *Authorization Code* as the Grant Type?

Should they use the APIM client ID and client secret (A), the customer application's client ID & client secret (B), or something else?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is right, but I added two client secrets for the Client Application App Registration (B), one for the developers and one for the client application, so developers don't know and aren't using the same key that the client's actual application would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can provide the developers with a separate client secret that is
> only meant for testing purposes, while the actual client application
> continues to use its own client secret for production usage.
> But make sure to maintain strict control over the client secrets and
> ensure that they are only shared with authorized parties and kept
> securely.

You can use **customer application's** client ID & client secret (B)
to test APIM using *Authorization Code* as the Grant Type in Postman.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created two app registrations i.e, APIM App and ClientApp in my Azure AD tenant.

Now, I exposed an API with scope `access_as_user` and added `ClientApp` as **Authorized** client application in APIM App like below:

[image]

You can find above scope in ClientApp's **API permissions** like this:

[image]

Now add those **permissions** in your application by following below steps:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to added permissions like this:

[image]

Before generating **access token** via Postman, I added below environment variables:

```
clientAppId: <appID of ClientApp>
clientAppSecret: <secret from ClientApp>
authUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
authTokenUrl: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

[image]

To generate **access token** using  *Authorization Code* as the Grant Type, I filled required fields like this:

[image]

When you select `Get New Access Token` button, it will ask you to sign in like below:

[image]

After successful authentication, I got **access token** like below:

[image]

To **confirm** that, you can decode the access token by pasting it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) and check below claims:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.  Your original statement of, "You can use customer application's client ID & client secret (B) to test APIM..." is understood and works, but is that a best practice?  I.e., having developers use the client application's secret for testing?  Your setup works just fine, but is it a best practice?  

I created a second client secret in the Client app registration (under "certificates and secrets" in Azure AD's App registrations) that for now will be the one developers can use and isn't the same secret the Client application itself will use.

Comment: You can provide the developers with a separate client secret that is only meant for testing purposes, while the actual client application continues to use its own client secret for production usage. But make sure to maintain strict control over the client secrets and ensure that they are only shared with authorized parties and kept securely.

Comment: Thank you.  If you include this information at the head of your excellent response post, I'll mark it as the solution.